# How To Specify Different Streaming Endpoint When Creating An OnDemand Streaming Locator

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I have two Azure Media Streaming Endpoints defined: the default endpoint that was created before September 11 2014 and does not support https, and a new streaming endpoint that was created after September 11 2014 and does support https.

I have removed all streaming units from the default streaming endpoint and have turned the default streaming endpoint off. The new streaming endpoint is enabled and has a single streaming unit.

When I create a Locator for my asset I need the locator to return the base uri of the new streaming endpoint, however it returns the base uri of the default streaming endpoint. For example:

```
var locator = mediaContext.Locators.CreateLocator(LocatorType.OnDemandOrigin, asset, policy, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5));

// locator.BaseUri == http://example.origin.mediaservices.windows.net
// This uri points to the default streaming endpoint
```

How do I specify which streaming endpoint to use when creating a new locator for my asset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I was using an older version of the Azure Media Services Client SDK (v3.0.0.5). In newer versions the MediaContext class has a collection of Streaming Endpoints that make it trivial to find the endpoint you are after. The way I ended up solving this is as follows:

```
public void Example(CloudMediaContext mediaContext, IAsset asset)
{
    var policy = mediaContext.AccessPolicies.Create("Streaming policy", MaxMediaAccessPeriod, AccessPermissions.Read);
    var locator = mediaContext.Locators.CreateLocator(LocatorType.OnDemandOrigin, asset, policy, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5));
    var template = new UriTemplate("{contentAccessComponent}/");
    var result = mediaContext.StreamingEndpoints
                             .AsEnumerable()
                             .Where(x => x.State == StreamingEndpointState.Running)
                             .Select(x => template.BindByPosition(new Uri("https://" + x.HostName), locator.ContentAccessComponent))
                             .First();
}
```

I found the information I needed in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2015/03/16/from-the-mvps-manage-media-delivery-in-the-cloud-with-microsoft-azure-and-media-services.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

A locator (GUID) is valid for all your streaming endpoints in your Azure Media Services Account. To use your "new" streaming endpoint, take the locator URL and change it to use the "new" hostname.
This is how I did in AMS Explorer (see Asset Information / Locators). http://aka.ms/amse

```
string hostname = myNewSE.HostName;
UriBuilder urib = new UriBuilder()
{
     Host = hostname,
     Path = locator.AbsolutePath,
};
return urib.Uri;
```